# Latest verion of Unity and GoogleVR can't generate APK build and shows error with Android Manifestation script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm developing a VR app but at the time of generating a build for Android, it shows me an error with Android Manifest script..
Error: Android Unable to merge android manifest Error
Upon researching a little bit, it seems that the latest Unity and GoogleVR updates have some issues, but I couldn't find in other answers which versions of both of these are ideal for making a VR app..??

Comment: What is your error? You can use the latest Unity beta, it include the Cardboard SDK natively

Comment: @Ludovic Here: Android Unable to merge android manifest Error..
So does that mean I don't need to get GoogleVR assets from outside.. Btw I'm at the 5.5.0f3

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to convert your project to an Android build first, then;
Import the GoogleVR SDK (1.20) and allow it to do a script update (Unity Editor)
A second "update import" (Unity Editor Asset import from Google) should also run correcting several errors and the Manifest merge problem.

Using:
Unity 5.5.1f1
GoogleVR SDK 1.20

Also be sure you Android SDK's are up to date ;)

Comment: GoogleVR sdk on GoogleVR website do not show the SDK version, nor am I able to see it in the info of the file.

Comment: Go to the Google repository on Github, the version is always listed.
Also, on the Web Download Link, if you check the Release Notes, it will list the version number for what you are about to download
[link]https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest beta of Unity, the Cardboard SDK is already included in the Virtual Reality Supported devices. See screenshot:

[image]